# What is dynamic date?

Tags: excel

I want to know what dynamic date is and how to use it. I just know it is something in excel but really not clear. I searched on google some times but still found hard to understand.

Comment: Maybe some tags would help? What is this question about and what have you tried? Show some code please.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, it's a date generated by the `Today()` function, which updates automatically.

In an excel sheet, type `=Today()`. This will enter the current date. As this is a volatile function, if you save the file then open it tomorrow, it will have tomorrow's date.